# how to pass class object to string.format

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I am trying to pass object as a parameter to `String.Format` but it's not working throwing zero-based index exception as it's not getting object property to allocate.

How do I pass class object to `String.Format`?

```
class TestPrimaryObject
{
    public string userId { get; set; }
    public string param2 { get; set; }

    public string param3 { get; set; }
    public string param4 { get; set; }
}
```

I am passing object of above class to `String.Format`. Below are the values of object property:

```
TestPrimaryObject objTest = new TestPrimaryObject();
objTest.userId = "test1";
objTest.param2 = "test2";
objTest.param3 = "test3";
objTest.param4 = "test4";

string formatedString = string.Format("http://example.com?param3={0}&userId={1}", objTest);
```

Parameter might vary according to URL

How do I achieve this?

Comment: What is `type1` that are you trying to pass?

Comment: You define two parameters in your formatted string but are only passing one. I have no idea what it is you are ultimately trying to accomplish.

Comment: type1 will be any class object

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var objTest = new TestPrimaryObject {
    param1 = "test1",
    param2 = "test2",
    param3 = "test3",
    param4 = "test4"
};

var path = "http://example.com?param2={0}&param4={1}";            
//HttpUtility from System.Web;
var keys = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(new Uri(path).Query).AllKeys
                .Select(x => objTest.GetType().GetProperty(x).GetValue(objTest)).ToArray();
var formatedString = string.Format(path, keys);
//output - http://example.com?param2=test2&param4=test4
```

Comment: parameter list can be vary according to input url..If i remove take(2) then also it's works. thank you... In my case i want to compare url parameter name and object parameter name if it matches then assign the value.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want to achieve is not possible. I bet that you would like to get the behaviour, such that `{0}` and `{1}` would get replaced by `param1` and `param2` of an object. First of all, if this were possible, how could compiler know which properties you wanted to pass? Secondly, what if you passed `2` objects with `3` placeholders?

```
class Object1 {
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public int Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

Now imagine such scenario:

```
string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", new Object1(), new Object1());
```

Should the compiler take `2` properties of first object and one from the second or the other way round?

You have to explicitly pass properties.

```
string formatedString = string.Format("http://example.com?var1={0}&var2={1}", objTest.param1, objTest.param2);
```

Comment: i am not going to pass two object it will always a one object but parameter name should match with variable name                                                string formatedString = string.Format("http://example.com?param1={0}&param2={1}", type1);

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you directly assign the values to url

```
objTest.param1 = "test1";
objTest.param2 = "test2";
objTest.param3 = "test3";
objTest.param4 = "test4";

string sURL = "http://example.com?var1="+objTest.param1+"&var2="+objTest.param2

//string formatedString = string.Format("http://example.com?var1={0}&var2={1}", type1);
```

Comment: No because every time object and URL will change. so string.Format statement will be in method which will have input as object and url.

Comment: So pass object to the function/method

Answer (score 0):

the error you're getting is because you want to show 2 parameters {0} {1} and you provide just 1 argument.

If you want the output to display the properties : I would recommend to override the ToString() function of the class. and work with a strategy pattern to change the behaviour accordingly.

Note that this is not an elegant solution.

```
void Main()
{
    var test= new TestPrimaryObject(){ param1="param1", param2="param2", param3="Param3", param4="param4"};

    Console.WriteLine(test);

    test.Formatter = new Param3And4();

    Console.WriteLine(test);

    test.Formatter = new Param1And2();

    Console.WriteLine(test);
}

public class TestPrimaryObject 
{
    public TestPrimaryObject(){
      Formatter= new Param1And2(); // set default here
    }

    public string param1 { get; set; }
    public string param2 { get; set; }

    public string param3 { get; set; }
    public string param4 { get; set; }

    public  IStringOverride<TestPrimaryObject> Formatter {get;set;}

    public override string ToString(){
       return Formatter.Format(this);
    }
}

public interface IStringOverride<T>{
   string Format(T arg);
}

public class Param1And2 : IStringOverride<TestPrimaryObject>{


    public string Format(TestPrimaryObject arg){
      return string.Format("http://example.com?var1={0}&var2={1}", arg.param1, arg.param2); 
    }
}

public class Param3And4 : IStringOverride<TestPrimaryObject>{

    public string Format(TestPrimaryObject arg){
     return string.Format("http://example.com?var1={0}&var2={1}", arg.param3, arg.param4); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve what you are trying to do with just a single call to `String.Format`. Since the number of parameters will vary, you need to conditionally be able to generate your url with an arbitrary number of parameters. You can create a method to do so:

```
publc string FormatUrl(string url, TestPrimaryObject objTest)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(objTest.userId))
    {
        sb.Append($"userId={objTest.userId}");
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(objTest.param2))
    {
        if (sb.Length > 0)
            sb.Append("&");

        sb.Append($"param2={objTest.param2}");
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(objTest.param3))
    {
        if (sb.Length > 0)
            sb.Append("&");

        sb.Append($"param3={objTest.param3}");
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(objTest.param4))
    {
        if (sb.Length > 0)
            sb.Append("&");

        sb.Append($"param4={objTest.param4}");
    }

    return $"{url}?{sb.ToString()}";
}
```

And call it like so:

```
TestPrimaryObject objTest = new TestPrimaryObject();
objTest.userId = "test1";
objTest.param2 = "test2";
objTest.param3 = "test3";
objTest.param4 = "test4";

string url = FormatUrl("http://www.example.com/", objTest);
```

It will return:

```
http://www.example.com/?userId=test1&param2=test2&param3=test3&param4=test4
```